# Is IoC feasible in winforms?

Tags: winforms, inversion-of-control

I'm coming back into the winform world after being in the web world for a while.  Is it common or otherwise feasible for developers to use IoC in winform?

My concern is mainly with performance.  I envision that I will need to "bootstrap" or initialize all my inverted items that are required by a given form instance on form initialization.  If this initialization becomes expensive, I can push the task off to a thread, but that requires that I get the created objects back to the main thread where they will be used at some point.

Comment: It depends on the developer... some do, some don't.

Comment: @Oded - Ok, I should have said "feasible" rather than common. I'm looking to see if I should use IoC at all. You are telling me the concept itself translates to winforms then. In a quick google search I did not find any 3rd party frameworks for IoC geared towards winform.  Right now I'm just rolling my own little inverter.

Comment: Correct - there is nothing stopping you from using IoC in winforms.  They are much better suited to it than webforms (no static almost unmockable `HttpContext` and other web baggage).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693690/ioc-di-framworks-with-smart-client-winform-apps-how-should-i-approach-this

Comment: IoC doesn't really need any frameworks. Dynamic DI does though, is that what you meant? Inversion of Control works simply through taking a dependency as an argument, either to a constructor or through a property. Nothing slow about that...

Comment: @Max - I think you are confusing dependency injection with inversion of control. IoC uses dependency injection, but the main difference from a developer standpoint is that I am able to decouple myself from my database.  I can switch between the DB and mock objects with the flip of a bool using IoC.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey You are completely correct, mixed them up :) What I was trying to say is this: DI doesn't need frameworks - IoC containers do though. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very common and I can't find many complaints regarding the speed of Unity/Ninject type resolution.

Your classes doing the heaviest lifting that have the most external dependencies you want to inject into should be nowhere near the Windows Forms framework code you're writing and so the fact that you're using Windows Forms shouldn't bare heavily on your decision (look into the MVP pattern for more on decoupling application logic from the types the designer uses).

Chances are those external dependencies you're trying to remove, by using IoC, will be *very* slow themselves and will be your real bottleneck.  In comparison to writing a 100k file or making a web request, it's not even worth thinking about.

Comment: The MVP pattern is what I've used for my WinForm apps.